# Docker API call returns "server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client"

Tags: go, docker, containers

I have the following Code and a Call to the API returns an error as follows, I hve also pasted Docker Daemon command below. I have tried a few combinations from HTTP/ HTTPS / TCP with / without TLS.

Where could I be wrong here?

*"panic: An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://172.28.8.212:2375/v1.24/containers/json?limit=0: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
"*

```
func main() {
    var headers map[string]string

    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }

    cl := &http.Client{Timeout: time.Minute}

    cli, err := client.NewClient("tcp://172.28.8.212:2375", "1.24", cl, headers)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    containers, err := cli.ContainerList(context.Background(), types.ContainerListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, container := range containers {
        fmt.Printf("%s %s\n", container.ID[:10], container.Image)
    }
}
```

My Docker Daemon is started as follows

```
[Unit]
Description = Docker Service Daemon
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --cluster-store=consul://172.28.8.211:8500
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this client api is used, but why are you supplying an `http.Client` when you're only connecting to a `tcp://` protocol?

Comment: 2375 is the HTTP port. 2376 is the default HTTPS port.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
func main() {
    var headers map[string]string

    tr := &http.Transport{} <---- Note the difference here. 

    tr.Dial = func(proto, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
        fmt.Println("Dial called")
        conn, err := net.DialTimeout(proto, addr, time.Minute)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("There was  an err", err)
        }
        return conn, err
    }

    cl := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
    cli, err := client.NewClient("http://x.y.z.w:2376", "1.24", cl, headers)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    containers, err := cli.ContainerList(context.Background(), types.ContainerListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, container := range containers {
        fmt.Printf("%s %s\n", container.ID[:10], container.Image)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that running your docker daemon without TLS and listening on a port is the same as enabling telnet with root and not setting a password on the root user. I wouldn't recommend doing this, anywhere, ever.

Comment: Yerek, Thans. I understand that, but as you can see I was just getting started back then.

Comment: Yup, just saw it pop up with the edit. There's lots of bad examples out on the internet, so I just wanted to be sure this came with a warning label before someone blindly copy/paste.